# using string array calculate polynomial value

Tags: c

```
char expressions[MAXEXP][MAXEXP];
int n_expressions = 0;
int expressions_curr_row = 0, expressions_curr_col = 0;
j=0;
for (i = 0; i < strlen(polinomb); i++){

    // this is a new expression
    if (polinomb[i] == '+' || polinomb[i] == '-'){
        expressions_curr_row++;
        expressions_curr_col = 0;
    }
    
    // put the expression
    expressions[expressions_curr_row][expressions_curr_col] = polinomb[i];
    expressions_curr_col++;
}
n_expressions = expressions_curr_row;

// print and check if it works
printf("Splitted expressions:\n");
for (i=0; i<n_expressions; i++){
    for (j=0; j!='\n'; j++){
        printf("%c", expressions[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
printf("\n");
printf("%c",expressions[3][0]);
}.
```

I have a polinomb string.

`polinomb[] = {"x+3x^3-5+7x^2"};`

for example: `polinomb[4] = '^';`

I created a new 2d string array and wanted to divide this polynomial using + and - signs.

But output is:

> x
> +3x^3
> -5

So program doesnt print +7x^2.

How can ı fix it?

Question2)
I want to take a number from the user and calculate the polynomial real value with the help of this string. (By writing the received number instead of x's)

How can I do this?

Comment: 1. At `for (j=0; j!='\n'; j++){` why `\n`? 2. You are not nul-termimating the strings with `'\0'`.

Comment: i dont see where do you assign a null at the end of the expressions in each string... and when you printf them, you search for '\n' .. where is that return carriage character assigned in previous code?, i dont see the sense. Anyways you must assign null when you find a + or a -  ebore you do the expression_curr_row++

Comment: expressions[expressions_curr_row][expressions_curr_col] =  '\0';

Comment: then you would be able to use printf("%s",expressions[i]);

Comment: About the second question , since c is compiled and it generates a binary, there is not exists that kind of functions (like eval in js). You would need to code your our expressions analizer and resolver.

Answer (score 0):

This must work.

```
char expressions[MAXEXP][MAXEXP];
int n_expressions = 0;
int expressions_curr_row = 0, expressions_curr_col = 0;
j=0;
for (i = 0; i < strlen(polinomb); i++){

    // this is a new expression
    if (polinomb[i] == '+' || polinomb[i] == '-'){
        expressions[expressions_curr_row][expressions_curr_col] = '\0';
        expressions_curr_row++;
        expressions_curr_col = 0;
    }
    // put the expression
   expressions[expressions_curr_row][expressions_curr_col++] = polinomb[i];
}
expressions[expressions_curr_row][expressions_curr_col] = '\0';
n_expressions = expressions_curr_row;

// print and check if it works
printf("Splitted expressions:\n");
for (i=0; i<n_expressions; i++){
    printf("%s\n", expressions[i]);
}
```

About second question, as i told you i comment, since c is compiled and it generates a binary, there is not exists that kind of functions (like eval in js). You would need to code your our expressions analizer and resolver.

I would separate all the operations possible (including + , - , * , / , ^), replace the variables for its values, and resolve based in operation priorities (first pow, after mult and division, and finally rest and sum).

To split operations i would do something like this:

```
char expressions[MAXEXP][MAXEXP];
int n_expressions = 0;
int expressions_curr_row = 0, expressions_curr_col = 0;
j=0;
for (i = 0; i < strlen(polinomb); i++){

    // this is a new expression
    if (polinomb[i] == '+' || polinomb[i] == '-' || polinomb[i] == '*' || polinomb[i] == '/' || polinomb[i] == '^' ){
        expressions[expressions_curr_row][expressions_curr_col] = '\0';
        expressions_curr_row++;
        expressions_curr_col = 0;
        expressions[expressions_curr_row][0] = polinomb[i]; //save operator in one row alone
        expressions[expressions_curr_row][1] = '\0'; 
        expressions_curr_row++;
    }
    else
        expressions[expressions_curr_row][expressions_curr_col++] = polinomb[i];
}
expressions[expressions_curr_row][expressions_curr_col] = '\0';
n_expressions = expressions_curr_row;

// print and check if it works
printf("Splitted expressions:\n");
for (i=0; i<n_expressions; i++){
    printf("%s\n", expressions[i]);
}
```

then replace variables and then resolve with operation priorities